# GWT NoSuchElementException with HTMLPanel and addAndReplaceElement method

Tags: java, html, exception, gwt, gwt-2.4

Here some explanations.

If my HTML page contains :

```
<div id="cancel_date">
  <h3 id="cancel_date_title"></h3>

  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td id="cancel_date_labelDetailService"></td>
      <td id="cancel_date_detailService"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If my code contains

```
HTMLPanel container = HTMLPanel.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("cancel_date"));

public void init(){
 container.add(getMyWidget(), "cancel_date_detailService");
}

public void reload(){
container.addAndReplaceElement(getService(), "cancel_date_detailService");
}
```

The first time I load my page, I initialize it with the method init(). The second time and after, I call the method reload().
The first time I call the method reload(), everything works fine. But after, I have a NoSuchElementException like this :

```
ERROR: Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus.castFireEvent(EventBus.java:69)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:57)
    at be.mims.bookme.client.gui.component.MyCellTableFuturDates$7.onSuccess(MyCellTableFuturDates.java:134)
    at be.mims.bookme.client.gui.component.MyCellTableFuturDates$7.onSuccess(MyCellTableFuturDates.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: cancel_date_detailService
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:224)
    at be.mims.bookme.client.gui.FactoryCancelDate.showCancelDate(FactoryCancelDate.java:128)
    at be.mims.bookme.client.BookMe.show(BookMe.java:277)
    at be.mims.bookme.client.event.StateEvent.dispatch(StateEvent.java:31)
    at be.mims.bookme.client.event.StateEvent.dispatch(StateEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:52)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus.castFireEvent(EventBus.java:67)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:57)
    at be.mims.bookme.client.gui.component.MyCellTableFuturDates$7.onSuccess(MyCellTableFuturDates.java:134)
    at be.mims.bookme.client.gui.component.MyCellTableFuturDates$7.onSuccess(MyCellTableFuturDates.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And if I go into the SimpleEventBus class where is the exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: cancel_date_detailService
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel.addAndReplaceElement(HTMLPanel.java:224)
at be.mims.bookme.client.gui.FactoryDetailRdv.showDetailsDate(FactoryDetailRdv.java:72)
at be.mims.bookme.client.BookMe.show(BookMe.java:228)
at be.mims.bookme.client.event.StateEvent.dispatch(StateEvent.java:31)
at be.mims.bookme.client.event.StateEvent.dispatch(StateEvent.java:1)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:52)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus.castFireEvent(EventBus.java:67)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:57)
at be.mims.bookme.client.gui.component.MyCellTableFuturDates$7.onSuccess(MyCellTableFuturDates.java:130)
at be.mims.bookme.client.gui.component.MyCellTableFuturDates$7.onSuccess(MyCellTableFuturDates.java:1)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor166.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I use GWT 2.4.0

Thanks a lot for help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its name implies, `addAndReplaceElement` find the element and *replaces* it with the given widget. Once you called `addAndReplaceElement` once for an element, that one element is gone, so the second call obviously won't find it, resulting in the `NoSuchElementException` you're seeing.

If you ever want to replace your widget with another, then you need to *wrap* it in an element  (i.e. call `add` instead of `addAndReplaceElement`), and use `remove` to remove the previous widget.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a look at your getService() method, but my best guess is that after you call reload() the 1st time the element it's looking for is being replaced.   Every other time, the block to be replaced no longer exists, throwing the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the problem comes from the html element cancel_date_detailService... I update my post